# Rundeck stops running throwing 'http error 503' while configure the mysql in rundeck-config.properties file

Tags: mysql, rundeck

After configuring mysql database in rundeck-config.properties when we run the rundeck url on browser it gives "http Error: 503 , service Unavailable" message in browser.

Answer (score 1):

Its strange to answer own question.
But there is solution we found for it, here the issue is because of permissions setup in mysql server side.
I have used following approach to set user level permission to the remote users:

CREATE USER 'username'@'remote_server_IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'remote_server_IP' WITH GRANT OPTION;
grant ALL on rundeck.* to 'rundeckuser'@'mysql_server_IP' identified by 'password' ;

once we have setup the permission the issue is resolved.